# Convert two single dimension array into one multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a two array

```
var arr1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
var arr2 = [23,32,11,35,15]
```

how do i get this ?

```
var result = [[0,23],[1,32],[2,11],[3,35],[4,15]]
```

Comment: are the two input arrays guaranteed to be the same length?

Comment: yes they will have same length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, do the following:

1. Compare the lengths to be equal.
2. Combine the arrays and create a new one.

```js
var arr1 = [0,1,2,3,4];
var arr2 = [23,32,11,35,15];
var result = [];

if (arr1.length === arr2.length)
  result = arr1.map(function (cur, idx) {
    return [cur, arr2[idx]];
  });
console.log(result);
```

More shorter version using ES 6 arrow function:

```js
var arr1 = [0,1,2,3,4];
var arr2 = [23,32,11,35,15];
var result = [];

if (arr1.length === arr2.length)
  result = arr1.map((cur, idx) => [cur, arr2[idx]]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the two input arrays are the same length:

```
var result = arr1.map((item, idx) => [item, arr2[idx]])
```